# Webpage text/javascript using Google Fusion Table Map not displaying

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-sites

After weeks of struggling I hope someone can offer assistance. I have a file hosted on Google Drive. When opening the same html file saved on my computer, it displays perfectly though the browser. But, when opening from Google Drive (or any other host I've tried, the embedded map (from fusion tables) will not show - only the search box feature will show. Here are the related documents/codes:

Html code: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwnxTTLxHzbzNkZ1MElZUGtpd3c/edit?usp=sharing

Webpage (displays only search box and not map/data): https://googledrive.com/host/0BwnxTTLxHzbzSUJJanFka2p3bEk/

I don't know why but the html file, when saved and opened from my computer, displays wonderfully in the browser. But, when uploaded and then accessed, does not display correctly. Please advise if able.

Comment: Take a look into the console : *[blocked] The page at https://googledrive.com/host/0BwnxTTLxHzbzSUJJanFka2p3bEk/ ran insecure content from http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false*

Comment: Why is this tagged google-maps-api-2?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTablesMap.html

Have you tried loading the Google Maps Javascript API v3 script using https:?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API

The version on googledrive gives a warning;

```
[blocked] The page at https://googledrive.com/host/0BwnxTTLxHzbzSUJJanFka2p3bEk/ ran insecure content from http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false.
```

And an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined (index):52
```